# Is it possible to change /pictures/wallpapers which is used automatically when selecting "use as background image"?

Tags: nautilus, directory, desktop-background

is it possible to change of /pictures/wallpapers which is used automatically when selecting "use as background image" on a picture in a folder?

I have read in another thread that this specific folder is hardwired into nautilus, which is kind of inhibiting the setup for me. 
It automatically makes a local copy of the picture, whereever the picture might be, to /pictures/wallpapers, and I don't want that.

The folder/ the issue is not mentioned in the "marked as duplicate:XDG paths".

I see no way to change this, can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

No, the folder `~/Pictures/wallpapers` is not hardwired in Nautilus and you can put your wallpapers wherever you like.

It is the folder Pictures that is (more or less) hardwired. That is, there is one folder called `~/Pictures` in your home directory, that is listed in the Locations in the side bar. To change that, you would need to modify a configuration file somewhere, if you'd want to access your pictures anywhere else.

But your collection of wallpaper pictures can be anywhere. At startup, your choice of wallpaper is retrieved from its last known location, and displayed. If you set your wallpaper to some other file, it is displayed no matter where it is. As long as the location is available at startup time, they could e.g. be on a network share or external disk.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the information. Every time I select "use as background", ubuntu makes a file copy to /pictures/wallpapers and I can't seem to get around this.  How do I circumvent this? Copying the file into /usr/share/background doesn't make it appear in the pictures list for choice of background.